# Unable to take incremental backup because of binlog size is more than 1gb

Tags: mysql

Even if I forced fixed in configuration file and by using global variables to 1gb... Some binlogs are getting more than 1gb to 15gb... And while importing those big binlogs data mismatch is coming...no able to do incremental properly...

I forced in configuration file as `max_binlog_size=1gb` still I'm getting same

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the variables like this?

```
expire_logs_days = 7

mysql max_binlog_size = 1G
```

**Result:**

you set the max binlog size at 1gb but finally get more than 1gb to 15gb.

**Reason:**

MySQL Server will append a numberic extention to each binaty log and this number will increase each time you start the server or flush the logs. A new binary log is also automatically created if the current log size reaches the "max binlog size".

If you are using large transactions, the binary log can exceed the "max binlog size". Because the entire transaction is wirtten into one binary log while not be split across different binary logs, you finally see that the binlog exceeds the difined max size.

**Solution:**

Before executing large transactions, turn off the setting  (which is enabled by default) by using

```
set session sql_log_bin=0
```

Do not add "global" like

```
set global sql_log_bin=0
```

as this will cause none of the statements executed on the Master database to be recorded in the binlog.

The root cause is the large transaction so you should locate and split up it.